# Ошибка при поиске по XPATH в selenium + python

Tags: python, selenium

Используя python + selenium geckodriver пытаюсь в таблице найти выпадающий список и кликнуть по нему. Но всё время выпадает ошибка "Unable to locate element".

Код на котором всё валится:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//td[2][class=' TMClassEdit TMClassChangedCell TMClassFocusedCell TMAlignLeft TMCellBase TMType TMEnum TMCell TMEnumLeft TMSideLeft HideCol11Plan15_']").click()
```

Можете подсказать, как решить проблему?

Comment: вы хотя бы сайт/html предоставили, мож у вас ошибка в локаторе

Comment: `Можете подсказать, как решить проблему?` не юзать XPATH

Comment: А что юзать надо?

Comment: `cssSelector` и код предоставьте html

Comment: выложите HTML код страницы, без него сказать где вы ошиблись в адресе xPath невозможно, так как сам xPath написан без ошибок, а значит проблема локации по классу, который вы выбрали. А вот товарищЪ tCode просто высказал своё мнение, вероятно потому что, где-то xPath ему не угодил. На самом деле, xPath и CSS-selectors имеют почти идентичный функционал и в принципе для локации по элементам достаточно знать что-то одно.